# Voltage Current and Circuit

Tags: voltage, current

What does short circuit and open circuit mean ?
I mean practically what does short circuit & open circuit means?

Comment: No resistance and infinite resistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practically, "short circuit" means that the impedance or resistance between two points is very low. Generally it implies that the two points are not connected together by design. The connection is due to some sort of fault, or may have been done deliberately for test purposes.

Open circuit means that the impedance or resistance between two points is very high. There is no conductive path between the two points. Sometimes an open circuit is not the result of a fault. I mean, the implication of fault is weaker with "open circuit" than it is with "short circuit."

Comment: An open circuit could also be caused by an open switch for instance.

Comment: Short circuits are not always faults; you could say "when this button is pressed, it shorts these two pins" for example.

Answer (score 2):

A short circuit is generally an unintended electrical connection between two or more nodes in a circuit.

An open circuit is an generally an unintended electrical disconnection in the circuit.

However there may be some exceptions where a short circuit or open circuit would be desired if properly designed. Such as removing a section of a circuit or bypassing a part of a circuit.

Here's a simple circuit. It works. The LED lights up. Happy.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbs0LB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I were to short circuit my circuit, with either SC A, or SC B (both are unintended electrical connections), my circuit will not behave as I desired.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Gz0Y.png)</sup>

If we were to open circuit or original circuit, there are 4 places we can open it. OC A, OC B, OC C and OC D. If any one of those open up, our circuit will not work as desired.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqoYo8.png)</sup>

Comment: In the SC case, a 3rd situation is possible: a SC between both ends of the resistor.

Comment: @glglgl you're right. Missed that.